# Facing error when I make a POST request to create entity in Dynamics CRM from Postman?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am having trouble making a successful HTTPS Post Request to Dynamics 365 CRM customer service.

I am able to successfully place GET requests but facing issue while creating new account/contact/incident.

Request body:

```
{
    "name": "MS account test",
    "customerid_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(904d1761-b522-ed11-9db2-000d3af06307)"
}
```

Please help!!

I get the following error: "An undeclared property 'customerid' which only has property annotations in the payload but no property value was found in the payload. In OData, only declared navigation properties and declared named streams can be represented as properties without values."

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind contact Record.

For Account Entity, when you are trying to add contact as lookup, field name should be `primarycontactid`.

For incident entity it will be below 3 field

```
primarycontactid@odata // Lookup
msa_partnercontactid // Lookup
responsiblecontactid // Lookup
```

for Contact it will be

```
parent_contactid
```

Comment: did this solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

for relationships you need to use the navigation property instead of the lookup name (they can be equal but is not always the case).

as you mentioned 3 different tables (account, contact, incident) you can create the request using my tool [Dataverse REST Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB), inside the generated code you can see the name or you can export the collection to Postman to see the raw request.